# Sum of the inverse of eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a symmetric $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \neq 0$, is there a way to find $\sum \lambda_i^{-1}$ without finding the actual eigenvalues?

Comment: $\sum \lambda_i^{-1}$ is the trace of $A^{-1}$, so it suffices to find $A^{-1}$ first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compute the characteristic polynomial:

$$\chi_A(x)=x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}\dots + a_0$$

then $\sum \lambda^{-1} = -\frac{a_1}{a_0}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is equal to trace($A^{-1}$), $A$ being symmetric or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:
$$\sum_{\forall k} \lambda_k^{-1} = \sum_k \frac{\prod_{l\neq k} \lambda_l}{\prod_l \lambda_l}$$

Which is the sum of the determinants of the principal minors divided by the total determinant in case you have those available or easy to calculate.